# Is there an already existing EOF character in python?

Tags: python, eof

I need to write for loop for which I need end of file character in python. Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you reading character by character? Its a waste of resources.

Comment: I get your point. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` of files returns an empty string when `EOF` is encountered.

```
while True:
    chunk = fp.read(1)
    if chunk == '':
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to output a line break character `print` would send the `EOF` automatically. So you don't have to worry about it. Just use `print` in the `for` loop.

If you're reading from a file `fp.read` returns `None` when `EOF` is reached.

```
while True:
    data = fp.read()
    if not data: break
```